# Как получить значение атрибута в теге html с помощью питона?

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно получить значение атрибута в теге html. Как это сделать, не знаю.

```
<img class="icon-btn" border="0" src="../../admin/images/view0.gif" onmouseover="src=&quot;../../admin/images/view.gif&quot;" onmouseout="src=&quot;../../admin/images/view0.gif&quot;" onclick="open_win('../../project/questions/question_view.php?qst=C12A1898F6A3BC4A4CE7BA6DE9C331A9&amp;md=qprint',750,450,'previewwnd')" title="Показать задание в отдельном окне" align="absmiddle" style="cursor:pointer">
```

вытащить нужно значение атрибута **onclick**

Comment: вытащите значение атрибута правильно будет сказать

Comment: @МихаилКамахин Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Просто ищем с помощью find в img

```
soup = soup.find('img',class_='icon-btn').find('onclick').text[k]
```